# How can simply send info to stdout in a Test?

Tags: perl, testing

It appears that simply putting a `say`, `print`, etc into a `.t` doesn't work. The output is hidden. So when using `Test::More` and `Test::Tester` how can I simply print something? I want this so I can play with some code while determining how to test it. note: it's ok if it's sent to stderr or only viewable using verbose. Also I dried using `diag` but that didn't appear to work just anywhere in the test.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you run a test script directly, you will see the output of `print` -- tests are just Perl code. However, if you run your tests using a harness, what you see in the output will be determined by the harness, especially its verbosity level, and by whether you print to `STDOUT` or `STDERR`.

For another way to print messages within tests, see [Diagnostics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore#Diagnostics) in the documentation for `Test::More`, notably:

```
diag(...);
note(...);
```

Experimenting with a script like this will quickly illustrate how things work:

```
# Example usages:
#     perl     some_test.t   # We see everything in output.
#     prove    some_test.t   # We see only diag() and STDERR.
#     prove -v some_test.t   # Everything again.

# In some_test.t
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

pass;

diag("diag()");
note("note()");
print        "STDOUT\n";
print STDERR "STDERR\n";

done_testing;
```

Comment: Also check out `diag explain ...` for easily outputting more complex data structures