# How to print hash keys inside unit tests?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

One of my unit tests gives this error:

```
#   Failed test at t/test.t line 53.
#                   'HASH(0x55fd82c77b80)value'
#     doesn't match '(?-xism:'value')'
```

Which make me think that a subroutine that I thought returned a string actually returns a hash. Notice that my override of this sub is:

```
sub foo {
    return $self->SUPER::foo($arg1, $arg2, $arg3).'value';
}
```

Since I have no idea why this happens, I want to print all the keys of the hash. There are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071229/printing-perl-hash-keys) of questions about how to do print hash keys in perl, but how to do it in unit tests (where you can't simply `print`)?

Comment: Here are some examples: [Test diagnostic messages using diag, note, and explain](https://perlmaven.com/diag-note-explain)

Comment: It's probably easier just to show the subroutine and have us diagnose the problem

Comment: @HåkonHægland `diag explain $result` did the trick, thank you! If you post it as an answer I'll choose it

Comment: @justHelloWorld Sure I would like to, but now I found a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162647/how-can-simply-send-info-to-stdout-in-a-test). Maybe this question should be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Personally, I don't see any reference to `explain`, which is more useful for this case where I want to print the content of an hash. No?

Comment: @justHelloWorld Yes you are right I think it does not mention explain.. so maybe I will write a short answer then

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you use Data::Dumper and `diag` or the Test::More helper `explain`. I would just use Data::Printer's `p`, which sends output to STDERR by default anyway, so it doesn't mess with TAP. (You _can_ `print` from tests, but you need to produce valid TAP or it breaks your tests and `prove` complains).